# angular2以降のイベント補足について

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular2, angular4

angular2にて、[innerHTML]で埋め込んだaタグのクリックイベントを取得したいのですが、良い方法がありましたら教えて頂けると幸いです。イメージ的にはjqueryのイベント補足のような感じです。

```
$(document).on('click', '#id', function (event) {
 // 処理
}
```

よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました。

結果としてHostListenerというデコレータを利用してイベントを補足して値を取得する方法で実現しました。

```
//宣言
import { Component, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

// clickイベントを宣言
@HostListener('click', ['$event'])

onClick(event) {
　if (event.target.className == "") {
　//ここでいろいろ
　}
}
```

もっとよいやり方がありましたらご教授お願いします。